# Creating a querystring based on what option is selected from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, parameters, query-string

I have this drop down menu:

```
<select name="Filter" onchange="applyFilter(this);">
<option name="Item1" id=Item1 value="10.5">Test1</option>
<option name="Item2" id=Item2 value="27">Test2</option>
<option name="Item3" id=Item3 value="31">Test3</option>
</select>
```

I'm still learning javascript and am trying to write a function that generates/loads the querystring URL and pass the value of the selected item as a parameter. Each option in the drop down menu will need to have their own ID. This is the code I have so far:

```
<script language="javascript1.2" type="text/javascript">
function applyFilter()
{ 
var currentQS = '';
var currentObject;
var currentURL = '' + window.location.href;

currentQS = unescape(window.location.search);
var newQS = '';

currentObject = document.getElementById('Item1');
newQS = $Querystring(newQS).set(currentObject.name,currentObject.value).toString();
newQS = newQS.substring(1,newQS.length);

currentObject = document.getElementById('Item2');
newQS = $Querystring(newQS).set(currentObject.name,currentObject.value).toString();
newQS = newQS.substring(1,newQS.length);

currentObject = document.getElementById('Item3');
newQS = $Querystring(newQS).set(currentObject.name,currentObject.value).toString();
newQS = newQS.substring(1,newQS.length);

var newURL = 'http://' + location.hostname + location.pathname + '?' + newQS;
window.location = newURL;
}
</script>
```

Any help with this will is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `$Querystring` refers to, but you should be able to do it like this:

```
document.getElementsByName('Filter')[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
    window.location = 'http://' + location.hostname + location.pathname + '?' + this.name + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

However, a select menu might not be the best option for what you're trying to do. Take a look at this blog post: http://uxmovement.com/forms/stop-misusing-select-menus/

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately as part of a buisness requirement it has to be a select menu but I will keep this link for future reference. I tried your suggestion for the script and unfortunately it didn't work. I took another crack at it and was able to modify it a little.

Comment: `$('#categoryFilter').change(function() { window.location = 'http://' + location.hostname + location.pathname + '?' + $("#categoryFilter option:selected").attr('id') + '=' + $("#categoryFilter option:selected").val(); });`  Remaining issue is how to get set the first option to be the default when the page is loaded.